# Dropped ceiling for small area (6ft by 3ft)

Tags: ceiling

I want to install a dropped ceiling in our small powder room for access to our heat pump.

The area is 6 by 3. Instead of having a main tee in the middle, I wondering if I can install the dropped ceiling by using the wall mount and cross tees. How would I go about that? Is there a way to secure the cross tees to the wall mount? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sure. I assume you're using 2x4 tiles. If you fit your cross tees well there's no reason they need to be fastened in at all. Just lay them in there as you set your tiles. You might make sure that the wall angles are fastened as close as possible to where the tees come in. Otherwise, I'd have no concerns.